# Marketing Cloud - Sent IP?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a business unit with 3 IP's. We use all of them together and they rotate as per the configuration.

Is there a way to tie that IP back to a send, down to an email address level?

We would like to export this but can't seem to find it anywhere.

I know that they tied to send classification but since these are in a "pool", the send classification is the same and it uses all 3 IP's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible to identify which IP address in a pool is used to send a particular email to a specific recipient. There is an IPAddress field in the _Job data view, but this is unfortunately always *null* as per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5).